# Java memoize/cache with persistence, and source code as cache key

Tags: java, spring, caching, persistent, memoization

I am looking for a general purpose memoizer that can be applied to any method by simply adding an annotation/decorator above the method definition. For example, the Spring Framework provides @Cacheable.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

However, I also need the following features:

1. the cache should persist on disk, so that I don't have to recompute values when I run the code again
2. the cache key should be a function of the method's source code, so that if I change my code between runs, the memoizer does not mistakenly reload old results

In Python, Joblib is a pipelining tool that provides this exact functionality. Is it possible to get Spring's @Cacheable to do this? Or a lighter weight way?

In case this triggers anyone's memory, here is a list of tools that seem like they could be helpful. I haven't been able to do a deep investigation of all of them.

- Guava's Cache library
- AspectJ
- Ehcache (seems like this is more than I need)
- javax.cache
- Java Caching System
- Pipelining systems: pipe4j, Apache Commons Pipeline
- Tek271 Memoizer (not much documentation)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at [imcache](http://github.com/Cetsoft/imcache). You can use @Cacheable and imcache will persist evicted values to disk via EvictionListener.